# Is there a way to prevent a bash script from running certain commands if the script has to be run again?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I have a bash script that works at the moment. It gets an image and JDK 8 from a link and then runs a installer for the JDK 8 to move on to setting up another piece of software.

As I was debugging the script, I kept finding myself having to delete directories and even the java installation because when I introduce a fix and rerun the script, I have to wait for everything to download again and I have to worry about duplicate files messing up my current logic -which can probably be improved, but I'll go to the StackExchange Code Review site later.

At the moment, I would like to know what approaches there are to prevent commands -like downloading the JDK and running the JDK installer script all over again and others- from running again.

What kind of general approaches are out there for cases such as these?

For the JDK download and running the installer, I did think of simply checking for the existing of java on the system and if there is then bash would not not to run those commands.

However, there are other commands I do not want run and I do want to simply check, for example, the existence of certain files to prevent wget-ing them all over again and moving them -causing duplicates. (Should I maybe suck it up and do that anyway as that might be best practice?)

I did also think of perhaps, at each successful command, outputting like a 1 to a text file and mapping each line in that text file to the commands run in the script (like using an if statement to see if that command had a 1 or not in the text file) and if it was a 0, then the script would know only to run that command and never the 1s.

That sounded clunky to me and I am pretty sure that is not a good approach.

Comment: Maybe you should use a Makefile. It can check whether a target exists, and only run the command to create it when necessary.

Comment: @user27068 : Once the installation successfully completed, create a file with the current date as its content. If this file exists, you know that the installation was done and indeed run to the end, instead of being aborted, and can avoid doing it again. Also, you can later easily verify, when the installation had been done, if you need to know. And, you can force the installation to be redone, by erasing this file and running your script again.

Comment: you could also wrap single parts of your script in functions and trigger them by parameter given to your script (see `getopts`)